# No route matches error conflicts with rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I added a test to confirm an error I'm getting in my views.

```
 2) NodesController GET /nodes/:id should be successful
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @node.id
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:id=>"nodexyz.example.com", :controller=>"nodes", :action=>"show"}
     # ./spec/controllers/nodes_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However, rake routes seems to be fine

```
   nodes GET /nodes(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"nodes"}
    node GET /nodes/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"nodes"}
```

Why do my tests (and app) think that No route matches when clearly it should match the latter route?

Comment: What happens when you make the `id` simpler by say removing the periods? It looks like the router may be thinking the periods in the ID are in fact an invalid format being passed in.

Comment: post part of your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the error you're getting:

```
No route matches {:id=>"nodexyz.example.com", :controller=>"nodes", :action=>"show"}
```

Then I would say that the most likely issue is that the :id you're passing to the nodes controller is "nodexyz.example.com".  Unless you have specified otherwise, the default your controller is expecting you to pass is the record id from the nodes table that corresponds to the record containing the string "nodexyz.example.com".

If you'd like it to use the string rather than the numeric id, there are couple of different ways to handle this.  My recommendation would be to use the gem friendly_id, as its easy to use and prevents you from having to do some work.  Ryan Bates has a good Railscast on how to use it.

[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

[Friendly ID at Github](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)